# Azure SQL DacPac deployment failing when trying to drop a column even though /p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False is set for SqlPackage.exe

Tags: mysql, deployment, azure-sql-database, sqlpackage

Though I am using flag BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False in my Azure SQL Dacpac Deployment pipeline, it is ignoring the flag producing the following errors, Can someone suggest what I am missing-

```
*** Could not deploy package.
Error SQL72015: The column [Demo].[Demo_ORGS].[CompanyCD] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
```

I am using these 3 flags as of now, Still facing the same error-

/p:BlockOnPossibleDataLoss=False /p:AllowDropBlockingAssemblies=True /p:TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings=True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BlockOnPossibleDataLoss = False` can fail during deployment plan execution if data is present on the target that cannot be converted to the new column type.

For more information refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver15#properties-specific-to-the-publish-action).

You can visit to this [github link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11191), where other users have shared some solutions which might help you.

Comment: Thanks. Will check the link